# 'EventModel' must return a value from $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i changed my service (model) to use with this, and now is giving this bizarre error , I searched and found that it would be for syntax error, the value would not be returning, but I think in my case the problem is not this.

The error is:

```
Provider 'EventModel' must return a value from $get factory method.
```

And that's my code:

```
'use strict';
var EventModel = function($http) {
 this.url       = 'http://localhost:3000/api/events';
 this.$http = $http;
};

EventModel.prototype = {
    find: function() {
        return this.$http.get(this.url).then(this.extract);
    },

    extract: function(result) {
        return result.data;
    }
};

angular
  .module('siteApp')
  .factory('EventModel', [
    '$http',
    EventModel
  ]);
```

What could be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the way you have defined what you need to use is a `service` recipe and not `factory`.

i.e

```
angular
  .module('siteApp')
  .service('EventModel', ['$http', EventModel]);
```

If you register with a factory recipe the constructor needs to return the instance, in your case you are not returning anything, and no `new`ing up happens for factory recipe. Instead what you have a proper constructor and with your implementation you are typically looking for it to be called with `new` operator and which is what precisely a `service` recipe does.

Comment: Yep, i know.. what idiot i am, i didn't get that i wrote wrong --'. Thanks very much!!!

Comment: i will accept your answer in 6 minutes.. thanks really, somethings we spend so much time programming that we not noticed a typographical error.